# How to add headers when redirecting to an external url in angular

Tags: angular, authorization, springdoc-ui

I have an angular 9 application + spring service which are authenticated against keycloak. The problem is that i want to open the spring swagger link in a new tab from the angular ui. Currently I am trying to add the bearer token to the authorization header when calling the url, but without much luck.

This is a snippet of what i am trying

```
var currentUserObject = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser'));

this.http.get(this.swaggerUrl, {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUserObject.access_token
    })
  }).subscribe(() => window.location.href=this.swaggerUrl)
}
```

Comment: Yeah this won’t work (not anything to do with Angular). Does it not support cookies for auth?

Answer (score 1):

I use [this lib](https://github.com/damienbod/angular-auth-oidc-client) in my Angular apps to handle user authentication and Bearer tokens header (access-token refreshing, automaticaly add `Authorization` header to configured routes, etc.)

Also, this is not directly related but if your API is documented with Swagger, have you considered using [OpenAPI generator](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/generators/typescript-angular/) to generate an Angular client lib? It exposes very convenient services to query your API.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is possible. `window.open` nor any other means to open a link will support setting headers. As this would be a security flaw in the browser. In any case, if a server would expect something to be a parameter, it would accept it as a `GET`/`POST` param or maybe a cookie (this one needs same origin).

This is what I would do:

1. If I control the server: Accept the token as query string param, then set it as cookie in the response.
2. If I don't control the server: Create a proxy script (with Express for instance), that would sit between you and the server.
3. If you only want to open a single page, like a doc page or something, without navigation, then just create a new page in your angular app that would load the swagger doc using `HttpClient` or `fetch` and render the contents inside some `div`. Then open that page in new tab with `windows.open`. This would be an example:

   ```js
   const routes = [
     ...
     {path: 'view-swagger', component: ViewSwaggerComponent}, // Pass params to this route to load the right swagger resource.
     ...
   ]
   ```